# some confusions about pointer to an object

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

#### Question 1:what is pointer value?

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object54 or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively.

Does it mean that pointer value is the address of an object?

#### Question 2:How to understand that **the pointer value is unchanged **?

[[expr.static.cast]/13](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#13)

> Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible with a, the result is a pointer to b. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion.

Consider the below example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   int a = 0;
   void* tmp = &a;
   char* obj = static_cast<char*>(tmp);
}
```

According to the above quote,we know that the original pointer values of `tmp` is pointed to `a`,and the destination pointer values point to an object of type char,since they are not pointer-interconvertible,hence  the sentence **the pointer value is unchanged by the conversion** worked.Does it mean that `obj` is now a pointer point to an object of type `char` and  **dynamic type of the object is `int`**,if I misunderstand about `pointer value is unchanged`,what does this sentence mean?

#### Question 3: How to understand that `the result is a pointer to b`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct Data{
  int c;
}
int main(){
  Data d;
  void* tmp2 = &d;
  int* ptr = static_cast<int*>(tmp2);
}
```

we know that the original pointer values of `tmp2` is pointed to `d`,so the original pointer value point to an object of type `Data`,and the destination pointer point to an object of type `int`,and these two objects are pointer-interconvertible,So the sentence `the result is a pointer to b` worked.Does it mean that now `ptr` pointer to an object of type `int` and dynamic type of the object is also `int`?

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  I think these questions can be subsummed by the same question

Comment: I know you do, I'm asking for one question per question

Answer (score 1):

> > A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to or past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object or the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object, respectively.
>
> Does it mean that pointer value is the address of an object?

No.

This sentence structure *"A or B means X or Y, respectively,"* is read as *"condition A implies X, or alternatively condition B implies Y."*

So the sentence means both

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer to an object represents the address of the first byte in memory ([intro.memory]) occupied by the object ...

**and**

> A value of a pointer type that is a pointer past the end of an object represents the address of the first byte in memory after the end of the storage occupied by the object.

The *respectively* allowed the authors to de-duplicate the preamble I had to repeat when expanding it out like this.

And, after all that, your meaning wasn't quite correct even for the first case.

It means that a pointer, **if** it is a pointer to an object, represents the address of the object's first byte in memory. It doesn't say anything about the value of any pointer unless it is *a pointer to ... an object*.

It doesn't mean that every pointer value is the address of an object, because pointers can be uninitialized, or set to `nullptr`, or set to the result of a raw allocation which has not yet been turned into an object with placement `new`. A pointer can still hold the address of the object you just `delete`-d via the pointer, as well.

I know the standard isn't super easy to read, especially if you're not used to this style (or to English) - but that means you need to make some effort to read it *carefully*.

Comment: yes,In short,the pointer value represent a address of some stuff

Comment: NO. If you declare a pointer and don't initialize it, it still has a value. That value may coincidentally point to something, but is probably _not_ an object, and _may_ be an illegal representation that causes a processor trap on your hardware, and _may_ not have any physical mapping, causing a segment violation or bus error.

Comment: A pointer _to an object_ points to "some stuff". Not every pointer is a pointer _to an object_ in the first place, and the quoted paragraph doesn't say anything about those at all.

Comment: ,yes ,my meaning is that  the stuff could be an object or plain value

Comment: Or not exist at all, or represent a memory-mapped hardware device, or crash your program, or hang your OS, or set your CPU on fire if you try to dereference it. It could very much be neither an object nor a plain value.

Comment: _"A pointer can still hold the address of the object you just delete-d via the pointer, as well"_ No, it can't. [When the end of the duration of a region of storage is reached, the values of all pointers representing the address of any part of that region of storage become invalid pointer values.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.stc#4.sentence-1) Invalid pointer values don't represent addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that pointer value is the address of an object?

Colloquially, yes that would be quite true. More precisely though, it means that pointer value is an address. The value of an object pointer could be the address of an object, but it can also be an invalid pointer value, null, or indeterminate.

> Does it mean that obj is now a pointer point to an object of type char

Yes.

> if I misunderstand about pointer value is unchanged,what does this sentence mean?

Simply, the address is the same. `obj` is a pointer to `char` and it points to the same address where the `int` object is stored. But `obj` is not a pointer to `a`.

---

As far as I understand, the distinction between having a pointer to object b, versus having a pointer whose value is the same as the address of b is that you can always indirect through the pointer to b to access the pointed object legally.

Simply having a pointer to type T with same value (i.e. the pointed address) as another object does not by itself mean that it is well defined to access through the pointer. Even if there happens to exist an object of that type at the address (in which case you can get pointer to the object by `std::launder`ing the pointer). In your example though, it is legal to indirect through `obj`, because pointers to narrow character types are special.

In short, a pointer always points to an address. It may or might not point to an object at that address. There might be multiple objects with the same address (only in cases that involve sub objects). Not all addresses contain an object at all times.

Comment: Simply having such a pointer isn't well-defined whether you access through it or not

Comment: @eerorika  `Dynamic type only pertains to pointers in an inheritance hierarchy`,it's not true,because **⟨glvalue⟩ type of the most derived object to which the glvalue refers**,**an object of a most derived class type or of a non-class type is called a most derived object.**,[[defns.dynamic.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.defs#defns.dynamic.type),[[intro.object]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#6)

Comment: @Useless However,**dynamic type** does not only refer to inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @Useless  I think It's not true.If the **dynamic type** is only refer to inheritance hierarchy,How do you interpret [[basic.lval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8)?

Comment: @jackX Thanks for the link. It seems that the term is more general than I thought.

Comment: @eerorika  you are welcome.It just like if you use a pointer of type float point to an object  whose actually type is int ,then access them ,the program is UB,because[basic.lval](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#8),the type float is not dynamic type  int,so the rule I linked worked,instead type `char` can access an object of any type ,because  `a char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte type.` in my link

Comment: @Useless I think you misunderstand about [basic.lval]/8

Comment: @Useless **dynamic type** is _" type of the most derived object to which the glvalue refers"_. [The definition of most derived object](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#def:most_derived_object) says _"an object of a most derived class type or **of a non-class type** is called a most derived object"_. So, it is not exclusively in terms of inheritance. Objects of non-class types are most derived objects.